# Convert to a Polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Can someone convert $x=(3+\sqrt{2})^\frac{2}{3}$ into a polynomial ?

I got $x^3-6x^\frac{3}{2}+7=0$ for an answer..

I want to get rid of the fraction and make it look nicer.

Comment: What do you mean by converting a number to a polynomial?  Finding the minimal polynomial of which the number is a root?  That being the case, please note that what you've written down is not what most people would consider a polynomial.

Comment: In powers of $\displaystyle{\,\sqrt{2\,}}$. Something likes
$\displaystyle{a + b\,\sqrt{2\,}.\quad}$
$\displaystyle{a, b \in {\mathbb Q}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe:$$x=(3+\sqrt{2})^\frac{2}{3}$$Cubing both sides gives us$$\\x^3=(3+\sqrt2)^2=11+6\sqrt2$$Try to isolate that $\sqrt2$ term; we find:$$x^3-11=6\sqrt2$$Squaring gives us $$(x^3-11)^2=72\\(x^3-11)^2-72=0$$Expanding we finally end with $$x^6-22x^3+121-72=0\\x^6-22x^3+49=0$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What you've written down is not actually a polynomial: polynomials are only allowed to involve non-negative integer powers.

Assuming, as in my comment, that "converting" a number to a polynomial means finding the minimal polynomial of the number, you would do the following:

Start off with $x^3=(3+\sqrt{2})^2=11+6\sqrt{2}$. Can you manipulate this to find the polynomial you seek?